# c# unit testing file not recognised

Tags: c#, unit-testing

I was following a tutorial to learn some unit tests

I have installed a all libraries needed for it

and generated another test project based on the project

but it still looks like not picking it up.

'''

```
using System;
using NUnit.Framework;
using UnitTesting.Dundamentals;

namespace reservation.unitTest
{
    [TestFixture]
    public class Program
    {
        [Test]
        public void Test1()
        {
            Assert.Pass();
        }
    }
}
```

'''
[image]

[image: Dependencies]

Comment: It would help greatly if you showed your dependencies for the test project.

Comment: Dependencies added, thanks John